# WebRTC NavigatorUserMediaErrorconstraintName MediaDeviceNotSupported

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, google-chrome, webrtc

Presently, I am building and testing a WebRTC application.  At this time, I am using Node.js 5.7.0, with Chrome 48.0.2564.116 on Windows 10 and Mac OS X El Capitan.  This is the code base I am using:

https://github.com/buildar/getting_started_with_webrtc

The demo application works great when I have a caller and callee on localhost, but after adding TLS/SSL, I receive the following error on the caller when the browsers attempt to connect, where I get the same error if I use only Windows 10 or if I use Windows 10 with a Mac OS X callee:

```
NavigatorUserMediaErrorconstraintName: ""message: ""name: "MediaDeviceNotSupported"__proto__: NavigatorUserMediaError
192.168.1.65/:139 sending 'join' signal for call token:#1457130057392-5812
```

Also, I'm getting this error after opening the page:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.65/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

All that I've been able to find so far is this forum post, which has not been helpful:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/toJRI6n8KP4

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Please note that WebRTC works fine when connecting between two computers in my LAN, but fails when trying to get the same website working from my web hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make sure everything was set up properly in the Node.js web server (see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx), and also needed to kill Skype since that app was taking over the camera and microphone.

Furthermore, had to disable a bunch of Chrome extensions I had installed--I'm not sure exactly which one was preventing WebRTC from accessing the webcam.  I disabled extensions like:

- "Do Not Track Me"
- "Facebook Disconnect"
- "HTTPS Anywhere"
- "SSL Enforcer"
- "Skype"

In addition, need to open up ports for UDP in my firewall for my specific website and also allow Node.js through the firewall.

Finally, sometimes what is needed is a good old fashioned reboot, because it seems like some threads might somehow be holding on to the webcam and microphone.

Please note that I have found WebRTC works consistently with Node.js running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

**UPDATE:**

Also, it works when I use only Node.js as the web server, but when I try to debug using Node.js Tools for Visual Studio (see https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools) it still keeps giving me the MediaDeviceNotSupported error.